# Python - passing string and specific lists, combined into function

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, function, recursion

i want to pass string (dirPath + dirName[x]) to a function

i already tried 3 times to combining string and a specific list (only dirName[x])

it seems that python just rejecting it anyway even if i already convert it to another type.

is anyone know how i pass this string to Function?

```
layer = 0
dirName = []
#dummy value layer = 4,  dirName = [/a,/b,/c,/d], dirBruteForce(layer,vault)

def dirBruteForce(layer,dirPath):
if layer > 0 :
    #call again to make layered dir
    for x in range(len(dirName)):
        dirBruteForce(layer - 1, dirPath + dirName[x]) ##this line
#call end of the dir
elif layer is 0 :
    for x in range(len(dirName)):
        try:
            os.makedirs(dirPath)
            print(dirPath)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
###
```

try1:

```
dirBruteForce(layer - 1, dirPath + dirName[x])
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

try2:

```
list = [dirPath,str(dirName[x])]
dir = ''.join(list)
dirBruteForce(layer - 1, dir)
```

error2:

```
dir = ''.join(list)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

try3:

```
dir = ''.join([dirPath,dirName[x]])
dirBruteForce(layer - 1, dir)
```

error3:

```
dir = '-'.join([dirPath,dirName[x]])
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what the objective of your code, or that particular line is?

Comment: my object is to passing string ..
dirPath (a string) and dirName[x] (a string within a list)
to a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `dirPath` is a list. You need to convert it to a string (for example using `str.join()` if you just want all the elements concatenated) before you concatenate the next part:

```
''.join(dirPath) + dirName[x]
```

Comment: i just realised that dirPath is a list. there is a typo in my code. i should assign string to dirPath.